# Angular API request not reload variable using subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'am newbie in Angular, but for study i want to get data from API. However, I wait about 2 seconds for the response from the API, so my page loads and the variable to which I want to save the result of the sent request to the API is not displayed.

My API return JSON as List:

```
[
  {
    "idWebsite": Guid,
    "name": "string",
    "url": "string",
    "location": "string",
    "enviroment": "string",
    "lastTestedByBenchmark": "string"
  },
  {
    "idWebsite": Guid,
    "name": "string",
    "url": "string",
    "location": "string",
    "enviroment": "string",
    "lastTestedByBenchmark": "string"
  }
]
```

My Angular code:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'APITest';
  Websites = new Array<WebsitesListViewModel>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
     }

ngOnInit(){
  this.http.get<Array<WebsitesListViewModel>>('APIUrl').subscribe(data=>{
    this.Websites=data;
  })
}

}

export class WebsitesListViewModel{
  IdWebsite:string = "";
  Name:string="";
  Url:string=""
  Location:string="";
  Enviroment:string="";
  LastTestedByBenchmark:string="";
}
```

I read that in that case Observable should be used. Using the tutorial and documentation I wanted to do it, but the variable nested in widomu still doesn't refresh after receiving response.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'APITest';
  Websites$ = new Array<WebsitesListViewModel>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    //this.GetAll().subscribe(result=>this.Websites = result);
    this.GetAll().subscribe(response=>{
      this.Websites$ = response
      console.log(this.Websites$)
    })
    console.log(this.Websites$)
     }
     
  GetAll(): Observable<WebsitesListViewModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<WebsitesListViewModel[]>('APIURL')
  }

}

export class WebsitesListViewModel{
  IdWebsite:string = "";
  Name:string="";
  Url:string=""
  Location:string="";
  Enviroment:string="";
  LastTestedByBenchmark:string="";
}
```

*P.S. If in Angular constructor -> subscribe method I add console.log(Websites) in console i got API result*

Comment: Can you explain where and how do you want to render websites data?  Beside adding $ to end of variable means it is an observable but you jsut passed your response data in it

Comment: This code is location in app.component.ts. I want to show data in app.component.html. For do this i use `<div ngFor="let data of Websites">{{data.url}}</div>

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an async pipe,

here is how you do it in your HTML,

`<div *ngFor="let data of Websites | async">{{data.url}}</div>`

Comment: In this case i got error `Argument of type 'WebsitesListViewModel[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<any[]>`